# How to read and write a text file in PhoneGap.?

Tags: cordova

I want to read and write a file in PhoneGap Android and I tried [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File) example.
But I couldn't find any output. ie. I can't find where the file is getting saved and where to write. Can we manually create a file and write inside it or read from it in PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

try to find the file in the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse.

```
Window -> Show View -> File Explorer. In this one look for the path data -> data -> your.projects.package.name and search there for the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented several demos about phonegap.All works well. You have no need to create a directory or file for operation,however the phonegap  api does all these for you. Please show your code for easier to solve your question.

```
//some code I write
function fail(error) {
       console.log(error.code);
   }

   function getLogPath() {
       var d = new Date();
       return "log"+d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+d.getDate()+".txt";
   }

   function writeToLogFile(errorMsg) {
       try {
           window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
               function(fileSystem) {
                   fileSystem.root.getDirectory("phonegapLogFile", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(directoryEntry) {
                       console.log("log folder is created");
                       directoryEntry.getFile(getLogPath(), { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(fileEntry) {
                           fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                               writer.seek(writer.length);
                               writer.write("\r\n");
                               writer.write("\r\n");
                               writer.write("Log message-" + new Date().toLocaleString());
                               writer.write("\r\n");
                               writer.write(errorMsg);
                           }, fail);
                       }, fail);
                   }, fail);
               },
               fail);
       }
       catch(e) {
           fail(e);
       }
   }
```